# Existing SQLite Database cannot be used by SQlite-net-PCL

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm trying to create a Library App for an end user to check out and reserve books and I have an  SQLite Database that contains 2 tables - one for "Book" and the other for "User". I'm trying to switch over from a full SQL client interface to a local data storage concept but, I'm trying to use SQLite-net-PCL. But I'm consistently getting the "Couldn't Open" Error for a file that I know exists and is an SQL database that I created using SQLiteStudio. This is the code giving the error behind the error:

**The Code**

```
public static void InitializeDatabase ()
    {
        db = new SQLiteConnection(DependencyService.Get<IDataBaseHelper>().GetLocalFilePath("hogwartslibrary.db"));
    }
```

**Dependency Service for UWP:**

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof(DataBaseHelper_UWP))]
namespace MobileApp.UWP
{
    class DataBaseHelper_UWP : IDataBaseHelper
    {
        public string GetLocalFilePath(string filename)
        {
            return Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "\\Assets\\database\\" + filename);
        }
    }
}
```

**The Error**

```
An exception of type 'SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in SQLite-net.dll but was not handled in user code
Could not open database file: \Assets\database\hogwartslibrary.db (CannotOpen)
```

I know for sure that the database is being packaged with the application and I know for sure the database works. The issue seems to be either in the library or in my C# code. Could you guys help me out?

Comment: From the partial path in the exception it looks like ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path is empty?

Comment: @AlexK. Could it be because I'm running it through Visual Studio and not installing the appx

Comment: Sorry, no idea about that toolchain.